Interrupting the kernel 'Python 3.12.7' timed out. Do you want to restart the kernel instead? All variables will be lost
This might be a nooby question so bear with me.
Sometimes when I execute Python Jupyter Notebook cells on VSCode, they take too long and I want to terminate the execution so I click on the top-left corner of the cell, where there's a square and you hover over it and it says "stop cell execution".
However instead of interrupting the kernel I get a pop-up: Interrupting the kernel 'Python 3.12.7' timed out. Do you want to restart the kernel instead? All variables will be lost. This bugs me endlessly because if I click on Cancel the execution doesn't stop and if I click on Restart, well, I lose all variables and have to start again.
I can reproduce this behaviour just with this cell:
import time

time.sleep(20)

I'm using Python 3.12.7 (both the system installation and a virtual environment, the same thing happens) and Windows 11.
How can I stop the cell execution without losing all variables? I want to interrupt and NOT restart the kernel.

"I lose all variables and have to start again". You aren't telling us what you are trying to do? Jupyter is meant for interactive efforts. It isn't the most suitable for everything. And even when it is suitable, if you doing things that are causing you issues, you usually can start adding in ways to workaround this. For example, code that you doesn't involve very computationally expensive calculations so you can restart the kernel often and get back to your state quickly are the most suitable. If that isn't the case, you probably need more traditional computing or using ways to address this...

 If you insist on sticking with running Python in Jupyter, do you know about the magic command %store? Are you using it so you can restore things in the state without having to running computationally expensive calculations? However, you may be running tasks more meant for running with Python directly so you ways you can kill the tasks/jobs on the command line individually. I'd also guess you want to be using screen or tmux to run things in a way you detach and reattach later and saving your progress along the way. But you provide no such details and so it is hard to know.

You can, unfortunately, only interrupt the kernel in between steps in your code. Your example is perfect. Sleep is a single statement, so you have to wait until that time has passed, since the kernel will only be open for interruption after the current statement has finished execution.
